# Zend_Uri_Http: Invalid URI supplied when using Google Chart URI?

Tags: zend-framework, google-visualization, zend-http-client

My application uses Google Charts and using HTTPS. I need to display the Google Charts as "secure" images, otherwise Internet Explorer will complain about displaying insecure content. So, I am trying to download them (then link to the local file) using a `Zend_Http_Client` request, but I can't seem to do it.

The URI should be valid since I can click this link and view the image:

[http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x150&cht=bvg&chds=0,19&chd=t:19&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|2009&chxr=1,0,19&chf=bg,s,F2F0E1](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x150&cht=bvg&chds=0,19&chd=t:19&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:%7C2009&chxr=1,0,19&chf=bg,s,F2F0E1)

Here's the code I am using:

```
$chartUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x150&cht=bvg&chds=0,19&chd=t:19&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|2009&chxr=1,0,19&chf=bg,s,F2F0E1';
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($chartUrl, array('maxredirects' => 0, 'timeout' => 30));
$response = $client->request();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way I can achieve this?

### Work-around

Since the Google Chart URI uses "invalid" characters, it fails validation when constructing a `Zend_Uri`. This is what I had to do in order to download the Google Chart.

```
/**
 * Returns the URL of the Google chart image that has been downloaded and stored locally. If it has not been downloaded yet, it will be download.
 * @param string $chartUrl
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getLocalImageUrl($chartUrl)
{
    $savePath = realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/Resources/google-charts/');
    $hashedChartUrl = md5($chartUrl);
    $localPath = "$savePath/$hashedChartUrl";
    
    if (!file_exists($localPath)) {
        exec("wget -O \"$localPath\" \"$chartUrl\"");
    }
    
    return "/Resources/google-charts/$hashedChartUrl";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `$chartUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x150&cht=bvg&chds=0,19&chd=t%3A19&chxt=x,y&chxl=0%3A|2009&chxr=1,0,19&chf=bg,s,F2F0E1';`

[edit]
As mentioned in the comments, urlencode didn't fix the issue, but replacing colons with their hex value did.

Comment: the problem is that the Google Chart URL contains characters that are usually invalid (such as the colon character), so it is failing validation

Comment: Have you tried replacing those characters with their hex value? (i.e.: ":" turns into "%3A"). You can always check what each character should be by having a look at asciitable.com

Comment: I think the %3A worked. Change your answer to say "replace colons with  %3A" and I will accept your answer